# express-session rolling not working

Tags: node.js, session, express, express-session

I've seen lots of questions about this, but none of the answers has solved my issue. I'm using `express-session` and I want the users session to remain alive as long as the user makes a request before the coookie MaxAge expires, hence I'm using the `rolling` option. For testing I have the MaxAge expiration set to 30 seconds.

If I browse around with only a couple of seconds between clicks, the session appears to stay alive. If however I make a request then wait 20 seconds, the session expires and I get logged out even though I was well within the 30 seconds.

Here's how I have `express-session` configured:

```
var express = require('express')
, cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
, session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser(EXPRESS_SECRET));
app.use(
    session({
        cookie: { maxAge : 30000 },     //in milliseconds. 30 seconds for testing
        resave: false,                  //Save the session to store even if it hasn't changed
        rolling: true,                  //Reset the cookie Max-Age on every request
        saveUninitialized: false,       //Don't create a session for anonymous users
        secret: EXPRESS_SECRET,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongooseConnection })
    })
);
```

My expectation is that setting `rolling` to true should allow me to continually remain logged in as long as I click at least once in less than every MaxAge.

Is there something else I have to do to get this working?

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352179/express-session-rolling-session-expiry-configuration) suggested setting `resave` to true but it didn't change my results.
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24794410/2325676) suggested setting httpOnly to false, but no change for me
- I've tried with `secure` both set to true and not set, with the same results (My site is https)
- I've tried setting `saveUninitialized` to both true and false, with the same results.
- express: 4.12.1
- express-session: 1.10.3
- cookie-parser: 1.3.5

**Update:**

So strange, Ive been hitting the same page every 15 seconds and monitoring the `connect.sid` cookie in the Chrome browser tools, and it usually is reset by 30 seconds on every request but every now and then, it doesn't change when I make a request. Sure enough waiting another 15 seconds and the session expires and I'm logged out.

I've logged an issue with `express-session`: https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/391

Comment: try `resave` to `true`. You have used it as `false`

Comment: "This post suggested setting resave to true but it didn't change my results."

Comment: did you test it without MongoStore and using memory session?

Comment: I haven't tried that, no

Comment: Just heard from express-session on GitHub and they suggested upgrading to the latest version, as .rolling had some bug fixes in it in previous releases.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version has fixed the problem